# Flexible marshalling with JAXB

Tags: jpa-2.0, jersey, eclipselink, jax-rs, jaxb2

I'm hoping to have a flexible way of marshalling objects.  A verbose version for single objects and a less-verbose version for multiple object versions.

For example, consider my department model:

GET /locations/1:

```
  <location id='1'>
    <link rel="self" href="http://example.com/locations/1"/>
    <link rel="parent" href="http://example.com/serviceareas/1"/>
    <name>location 01</name>
    <departments>
      <department id='1'>
        <link rel="self" href="http://example.com/departments/1"/>
        <name>department 01</name>
      </department>
      <department id='2'>
        <link rel="self" href="http://example.com/departments/2"/>
        <name>department 02</name>
      </department>
      <department id='3'>
        <link rel="self" href="http://example.com/departments/3"/>
        <name>department 03</name>
      </department>
    </departments>
  </location>
```

GET /department/1:

```
<department id='1'>
  <link rel="self" href="http://example.com/departments/1"/>
  <link rel="parent" href="http://example.com/locations/1"/>
  <name>department 01</name>
  <abbr>dept 01</abbr>
  ....
  <specialty>critical care</specialty>
</department>
```

Is there a way to do this?  Would I need to have separate entity objects?  One that references the table for CRUD operations and another for lists?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) lead, and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Your question is tagged `EclipseLink`, if you are using **EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)** you can take advantage of the external binding document to apply a second mapping to the `Department` class.

---

**ContextResolver**

In a **JAX-RS** environment you can leverage MOXy's external binding document through a `ContextResolver`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;     
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

@Provider
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public class DepartmentContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext jc;

    public DepartmentContextResolver() {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
            props.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "example/bindings.xml");
            jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Department.class} , props);
        } catch(JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> clazz) {
        if(Department.class == clazz) {
            return jc;
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

---

**External Binding Document**

By default MOXy's external binding document is used to augment the annotated model, but if you set the `xml-mapping-metadata-complete` flag it will completely override the annotations allowing you to apply a completely different mapping:

```
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="example"
    xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    ...
</xml-bindings>
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

**UPDATE**

This update is to address a number of questions you asked in one of your comments:

> 1 . Should/can each ContentResolver have its own binding file?

Yes each `ContextResolver` should have its own binding file.  The main reason for introducing  a new `ContextResolver` is to represent a secondary mapping.

> 2 . Can I have more than one for each ContentResolver (this would give me a number of renderings of the same class, creating a 'view' of sorts), perhaps specifying its location in the constructor?

For a single `ContextResolver` you can express the metadata across multiple binding files, but they will be combined into a single set of mappings.  This means that a single `ContentResolver` cannot have multiple views of a single class.  A separate `ContextResolver` is used to represent a secondary mapping.

> 3 . Where should the binding files reside?

I recommend loading the metadata file from the class path.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html

> 4 . I can see how the ContentResolver could be easily specified in a Resource's GET method, but how would this be done if the object is embedded in another (JPA) object? In the embedded object's getter/setter?

Your JAX-RS implementation should pick up your `ContextResolver` because it is annotated with `@Provider`.  The `ContextResolver` used for a class will depend on how you implement the `getContext` method:

```
public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> clazz) {
    if(Customer.class == clazz) {
        return jc;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm referencing three, 'EclipseLink(JPA 2.0)' JARs: eclipselink-2.3.0.jar, javax.persistence-2.0.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_1.0.0.jar.  Is MOXy included in any of these?

Comment: @craig - MOXy is included in eclipselink-2.3.0.jar.  Here is an article that explains how to configure MOXy as the JAXB provider:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html  If you are using GlassFish the following article explains how the MOXy can be configured: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

Comment: I have a number of n00bish, JABX-related questions.  Would you have time for a chat in one of the SO rooms?

Comment: @craig - We could use the Java room.

Comment: OK, this makes sense, but I have a few questions.  1. Should/can each ContentResolver have its own binding file?  2. Can I have more than one for each ContentResolver (this would give me a number of renderings of the same class, creating a 'view' of sorts), perhaps specifying its location in the constructor?  3. Where should the binding files reside? 4. I can see how the ContentResolver could be easily specified in a Resource's GET method, but how would this be done if the object is embedded in another (JPA) object?  In the embedded object's getter/setter?

Comment: @craig - I have updated my answer to address your new questions.

Comment: wow, super helpful +1.  In addition to the implicit ContentResolver (enabled by the class' annotation), I can create additional, custom ContentResolvers.  Each of these ContentResolver has its own binding file. It seems that a custom ContentResolver will be chosen before the implicit one.  Is this accurate?  If I have multiple, custom ContentResolvers that *could* be applied to a given class, is there a way to specify which one to use?

Comment: Should have written ContextResolver instead of ContentResolver.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes another idea. Could be a bad idea but somewhat easy.

```java
class Department {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public Link getSelf() {
        return self;
    }

    @XmlElement(required = false) // default
    public Link getParent() {
        if (verbose) {
            return parent;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @XmlElement(required = false) // default
    public String getSpecialty() {
        if (verbose) {
            return specialty;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    private boolean verbose;
}
```