# How to add additional classes to JAXBContext in CXF

Tags: rest, jaxb, cxf

I need to use `<any>`element in my xsd for scalability. So i used xsd as like below.

```
<complexType name="AddInput">
        <sequence>
            <element name="First" type="int"></element>
            <element name="Sec" type="int"></element>
            <any processContents="lax" namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></any>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
```

I have defined a complex object to place into the `<any>` placeholder, with ObjectFactory (@XMLRegistry, @XmlElementDecl) But still if i run below code, i am getting

> org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl

instead of JAXBElementObject. I searched in google, i see that JAXBContext should know about the schema. But i am not sure, how to make JAXBContext know my complex object. Any idea would be helpful.

```
        List<Object> elemList = (List<Object>)input.getAny();
        for(Object elem : elemList){
            System.out.println(elem.getClass());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JAX-RS method like the following the `JAXBContext` used will be equivalent to making the following call `JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo)`

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("{id}")
public Foo read(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return entityManager.find(Foo.class, id);
}
```

If you want the `JAXBContext` to be aware of all the classes you generated from the XML schema you can associate a `JAXBContext` with the domain object using a `ContextResolver`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;     
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class FooContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext jc;

    public FooContextResolver() {
        try {
            jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo");
        } catch(JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> clazz) {
        if(Foo.class == clazz) {
            return jc;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Example**

- [Flexible marshalling with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086930/flexible-marshalling-with-jaxb/9089542#9089542)

Comment: I am using RAD to generate the JAXB classes. I didnt use any external binding file. First of all how the xml got converted into object in CXF. How to use the context used by cxf to convert the object. I didnt understood from the link you have give.

Comment: @Manoj - I have updated my answer to try an make it more clear.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance. I still couldnt get the point. When CXF databinding will know all the classes defined in the schema. Why it knows "AddInput" above alone and not the other one.?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set :

> jaxb.additionalContextClasses

see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55485843/1634131